# Solve the SDE: $dX = \cos(X)\sin^3(X)dt +\sin^2(X)dW$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Solve the SDE:

$$
dX = \cos(X)\sin^3(X)dt +\sin^2(X)dW
$$

where $W$ is a Brownian motion. The SDE has initial condition $X(0) = \frac{\pi}{2}$. I am given the hint that $\int dx/\sin^2(x) = -\cot(x) + C$.

My idea is to use Ito's formula - however I have no idea which function to try this with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint 1.* Let's use Ito's lemma for $f(t,X) = \cot(X)$.

*Hint 2.* It will give us: $\underbrace{[\ldots]}_{\star} dt + [\ldots]dW_t$. What will happen with $\star$.

Comment: Thank you very much, in general how do you find the function to apply Ito's lemma too. I assume you picked cot due to the hint, but if the hint weren't there, what would you do?

Comment: @Jamal first way to solve is to find such $f(t, X)$ to get rid of coefficient before $dt$. It may be hard to find a function dependent on **both** of the parameters, so it's easier to find one depended only on $f(X)$.